# setState is one step behind when using getValue() in material-ui <TextField/>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to update my states by grabbing the value in a text field using material-ui on click. However, it seems that setState is always one step behind in updating the todo state here. For example, if I enter 'asdf' the first time round, `this.state.todo` is empty (which is what it was initialized to). I then enter '1234'. On click, I now see that `this.state.todo` is 'asdf'!

**Question 1:** I think this may have something to do with the '[pending state transition](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)' of setState but am not sure how to resolve this.

When I used onChange and value with a vanilla (non-material-ui) input field, it all worked well.

**Question 2:** So I'm also curious as to why setState batched the process in the material-ui getValue() case but not when I used onChange/Value in input.

Below are codes for both varieties.

Material-UI TextField:

```
const Main = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactFire],
  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  getInitialState () {
    return {
      muiTheme: ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(LightRawTheme),
      todo: ''
    };
  },

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      muiTheme: this.state.muiTheme
    };
  },

  componentWillMount() {
    let newMuiTheme = ThemeManager.modifyRawThemePalette(this.state.muiTheme, {
      accent1Color: Colors.deepOrange500
    });

    this.setState({muiTheme: newMuiTheme});
    this.fb = new Firebase(rootUrl+'items/');
    this.bindAsArray(this.fb,'items');
  },

  render() {
    let containerStyle = {
      textAlign: 'center',
      paddingTop: '200px'
    };

    let standardActions = [
      { text: 'Okay' }
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
          title="Immaterial"
          iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more" />

        <div style={containerStyle}>
          <TextField
            hintText="Hint Text"
            ref="newTodo"
            />
          <Dialog
            title="Go get 'em Tiger!"
            actions={standardActions}
            ref="superSecretPasswordDialog">
            {this.state.todo}
          </Dialog>

          <h3>A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step</h3>

          <RaisedButton label="Carpe Diem" primary={true} onTouchTap={this._handleTouchTap} />

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },

  _handleTouchTap() {
    var todo = this.refs.newTodo.getValue()
    console.log(todo)
    this.setState({todo: todo});
    console.log(this.refs.newTodo.getValue())
    console.log(this.state.todo)
    // this.firebaseRefs.items.push({
    //   todo: this.state.todo
    // });
    //this.refs.superSecretPasswordDialog.show();
    //this.refs.newTodo.clearValue();
  }
```

Vanilla input

```
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {text: ''};
  },
  handleChange: function(event) {
    //console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({text: event.target.value})
  },
  handleButtonClick: function() {
    //console.log(this.state.text)
    this.props.itemsStore.push({
      text: this.state.text,
      done: false
    });
    this.setState({text:''});
  },

  render: function(){
    return <div className="input-group">
      <input
        value = {this.state.text}
        onChange = {this.handleChange}
        type="text"
        className = "form-control"
        placeholder = "getting things done!"
      />
      <span className="input-group-btn">
        <button
          onClick={this.handleButtonClick}
          className="btn btn-default"
          type="button">
          Add
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  }
```

Console output for material-ui TextField
[image]

Comment: Looks to me as if you're trying to log after a `setState` has passed in your MaterialUI case and before in your vanilla case. They will obviously do two differing things.

Comment: I was testing for something else there. Those lines are commented out. Ultimately I'm concerned with what gets updated in Firebase. Vanilla updates the current value. Material updates the value one step prior.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or jsbin with the current issue?

Comment: sure thing. gimme a sec.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't get material ui on to jsbin or jsfiddle. Here's my commit if it helps https://github.com/ee7klt/materialize-todo/commit/d18ec41a4a89c09d8485ae57a899566ea986bc8c